# how to use like command if we have ? _ % in our name in sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

example i have names containing % _ . ? or any combination of these in a particular table of my sql database so how can i search such words in a column using like command?

Comment: Escape `%` and `_` chars. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like Use REPLACE() function.

Comment: @VaibhavGupta . . . Use `=`.  Use `like` only if you want to treat wildcards as wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is logic for percent:

```
where col like '%|%%' escape '|'
```

Implement this logic for rest of your symbols.